# Facing issue running Qt C++ on Visual Studio Code : no output on console, no gui showed

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, gcc, cmake

I'm trying to have a Qt C++ environnement on visual studio code with cmake.
Without Qt everything works perfectly but when I want to use an object Qt, I got no output on the console (with cout or qDebug()) and the GUI doesn't appear.

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 
    std::cout << "My app" << std::endl;
    qDebug() << "My app";

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow msiWindow;
    msiWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I run it, I got no issue but nothing happen.

Here is my CMakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.3)

project(C++)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/g++.exe")

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp)

add_executable( main ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
```

My c_cpp_properties.json if needed:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Qt/6.2.0/Src",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Please tell me if you have any idea.

Comment: Try adding Core and Gui to components.

Comment: I just added but it doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my issue, I just forgot to add `"C:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\bin"` to my `PATH` environment variable.